# Prove that the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=2015$ has no integer solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=2015$  has no integer solutions.

Since $2015=251 \cdot 8 +7$  it follows from Legendre's three-square theorem.

Is there a more elementary direct way to prove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working modulo $8$ is a bit simpler. The only squares there are $1,4$ and $0$, and you can't get to $7$ by adding three such together.

This is probably the same way you would prove the three-square-theorem, except that we only do it in one direction (we don't prove that $2014$ *is* possible to write as the sum of three squares).

Answer (score 3):

If $k$ is a perfect square then $k\equiv0,1,4\pmod8$:

- $n\equiv0\pmod8 \implies n^2\equiv0^2\equiv0\pmod8$
- $n\equiv1\pmod8 \implies n^2\equiv1^2\equiv1\pmod8$
- $n\equiv2\pmod8 \implies n^2\equiv2^2\equiv4\pmod8$
- $n\equiv3\pmod8 \implies n^2\equiv3^2\equiv1\pmod8$
- $n\equiv4\pmod8 \implies n^2\equiv4^2\equiv0\pmod8$
- $n\equiv5\pmod8 \implies n^2\equiv5^2\equiv1\pmod8$
- $n\equiv6\pmod8 \implies n^2\equiv6^2\equiv4\pmod8$
- $n\equiv7\pmod8 \implies n^2\equiv7^2\equiv1\pmod8$

No $3$ values chosen from $\{0,1,4\}$ will ever sum up to $7\pmod8$.

Since $2015\equiv7\pmod8$, it cannot be expressed as a sum of $3$ perfect squares.